# Transfer RSA key from one computer to another

Tags: c#, .net, rsa

On machine "A" I create a RSA public / private key like this:

```
CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
cp.KeyContainerName = containerName;

// Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider that accesses  
// the key container MyKeyContainerName.  
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
publicKeyXml = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
```

That gives me the same set of public and private keys every time. I then take the public key and store it on computer B. I can then decrypt messages from computer A like this:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

// set the public key of the crypto service provider
RSA.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);

// create a deformatter
RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter RSADeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(RSA);

// set the hash algorithm. The sender must use the same algorithm
RSADeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm(hashAlgorithm);

// verify the signature
verified = RSADeformatter.VerifySignature(hashValue, signaturebytes);
```

My question is this: What if I want to send messages from a third computer, (call it C) to B? How do I transfer the keystore from A to C to guarantee that the same key pair is generated? I only have one place to store a public key on computer B. It needs to decrypt message from both A and C. Can I just copy the keystore from the windows folder over? Or will this work: Export the keys on B with ToXmlString(true) and import them on c with RSA.FromXmlString(). If I do that will it store it in the keystore on C?

Comment: "I only have one place to store a public key on computer B" - how's that?

Comment: First, you are not encrypting/decrypting, you are signing then verifying the signature. The concept is that a message signed with the certificate on computer A can be verified as coming from computer A without alteration as long as computer B has computer A's public key. So if you want to add computer C into the mix, you would sign the messages from computer C with it's private key and computer B would verify the signature against computer C's public key.

Comment: Yes, I'm signing, thanks for the clarification. The reason computer C is in the mix is for scalability (server farms, application services, etc.). Its effectively a clone of computer A.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Jaykul/8c65f10c0f09dd8e296365b70c48b577). It contains some powershell functions to export and import the RSA keys. We ran into the same issue, and used these scripts to tranfer the key

edit:
to clarify, I did not write the gist, I only found it and used it to solve this exact issue